# DIV on Google map

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I try to display DIV over the Google Map.
I know, there are many such questions on "stackoverflow", and many answers, but it didn't work in my example... :((((((((
My script:

```
<div class="b-map-content" id="map-content">
    <div class="temp">
    </div>
<div>
```

and styles:

```
.b-map-content{ 
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 550px;
}

.temp{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;   
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #FF0000;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

When the page loading  in some moment I see red square, but when map was loaded I don't see it again...

how it work You can see here: [enter link description here](http://mimameko.ho.ua/enviromap/)

I will be very glad for help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<div class="map-container">
    <div class="b-map-content" id="map-content"></div>
    <div class="temp"></div>
</div>
```

When Google Maps initializes, I am guessing that it removes all inner elements within `id="map-content"`, which is why you are seeing the flash of red.

Comment: @MamekoMikhail If that solved your problem, please accept this answer